# Returns 400 Bad Request by POST, PUT methods but GET is working okay

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to call POST/PUT (by using HttpClient, in Swagger or Postman it works) method but it is return 400 status code. It checks for database existing and returns 200.

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
  Executed DbCommand (27ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT 1
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
  Executed DbCommand (42ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

  IF EXISTS
      (SELECT *
       FROM [sys].[objects] o
       WHERE [o].[type] = 'U'
       AND [o].[is_ms_shipped] = 0
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM [sys].[extended_properties] AS [ep]
           WHERE [ep].[major_id] = [o].[object_id]
               AND [ep].[minor_id] = 0
               AND [ep].[class] = 1
               AND [ep].[name] = N'microsoft_database_tools_support'
      )
  )
  SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
```

Also I am using this part of code:

```
var user = new User()
{
    UserName = "bshelpw",
    PhoneNumber = "467-928-6562",
    FirstName = "Janine",
    LastName = "Quinevan"
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
using var client = new HttpClient();
string url = Client.BaseAddress + RequestType.User;
var response = client.PostAsync(url, data).Result;
```

I tried to use another API and it works fine but in my API there is no errors.

Comment: It seems you use httpclient post the data and get the 400 Bad Request error, right? Does your api contains `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute? What does the parameter like in your api? Does it declare with `[FromBody]`? 
 Pls share the api code if possible.

Comment: Yes, of course. I am share it upper

Comment: Hi @Arbross, I have checked your code and works fine. Pls set breakpoint to your Post method and check which line may does not work.  Only difference is `await _userService.AddUser(user);`, may be you need also debug the code and  share this service to us.

Comment: I am trying to use HttpClient from another project and it isn't even enter to the post method. I will share the await _userService.AddUser(user); in few minutes

Comment: Hi，if it even does not hit the post method, no need share the service. Could you pls share your `UserDTO`?

Comment: Shared User and UserDTO

Comment: Seems does not influence the result. Did you use ASP.NET 6? Because you just set UserName,PhoneNumber etc. property, .NET 6 will add the required validation for the non-nullbale property, e.g type of string properties. If you do not set a value for it, it will fail to model validation and receive 400 bad request error.

Comment: I tried to fill all the rows of class and it is no changes

Comment: If you use .NET 6, try to remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in the project file and test again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/nullable-reference-types#create-the-application-and-enable-nullable-reference-types) said:

> Beginning with .NET 6, new projects include the
> `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` element in the project file. Once the
> feature is turned on, existing reference variable declarations become
> **non-nullable reference types**.

In .NET 6 the **non-nullable property must be required**, otherwise the model validation will fail.

To achieve your requirement, you can remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project file.